# (Proof) Linear algebra - semi-positive and not positive definite bilinear form

Tags: linear-algebra

I need to prove the following statement.

> Let $V$ be an $n$-dimensional ($n\geq 3$) real vector space and
>   $b:V\times V\to\mathbb R$ a symmetric and non-degenerate bilinear form
>   which satisfies:
>
> (1) $b$ is *semi-positive definite*, i.e., $b(v,v)\geq 0$ for each
>   $v\in V$;
>
> (2) $b$ is not *positive definite*, i.e., there exists $v\in V$, $v\ne
> 0$ such that $b(v,v)=0$.
>
> Then there exists an unique subspace $l$ of $V$ such that $\dim l=1$ and
>   $b(v,v)=0$ for all $v\in l$.

This is my idea:

*Let $v$ be an element of $V$ such that $b(v,v)=0$ and define $l$ as the subspace $\langle v\rangle$ of $V$ generated by $v$. We shall prove that $l$ is unique. Consider $w\in V-l$ with $b(w,w)=0$. Then, given $\lambda\in\mathbb R$ we have that $w\ne\lambda v$ and so, $u=w-\lambda v$ is an element of $V-l\oplus l'$. It is easy to show that
$$b(u,u)=-2\lambda b(w,v)$$
Asumme that $\lambda>0$. If $b(w,v)>0$ then $b(u,u)<0$ and this is imposible by (1). If $b(w,v)<0$ we can replace $w$ by $-w$.*

Is it correct my reasoning?

Comment: Looks fine to me, it is preferred to give vector spaces capital letters though.

Comment: If $b$ is symmetric, non-degenerate and semi-positive define, it is actually positive definite... so there is no such $b$.